# How should I design an ASP.NET page for iOS to upload a binary chunk of data?

Tags: asp.net, html, ios, binary, asihttprequest

**The spec:** iOS app needs to POST binary data (a 5k section of a file) to an ASP.NET web application. For example: POST to http://mydomain.com/Receive.aspx?fileKey=2 with the contents of this POST being a 5k byte[] array.

Due to unrelated issues, web service call is not possible, so this is just a plain ASP.NET request.

Having little iOS experience, how should I design this page so that it's relatively easy for the iOS devs to use, and if there are any iOS devs reading this, how do you set up the `ASIHTTPRequest` for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create this as a method in an MVC controller. You get the benefit of very clear url and also it will wire up the post variables to come through the method.

A good example is here [Post and read binary data in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694185/post-and-read-binary-data-in-asp-net-mvc)

```
public ActionResult UploadChunk(Guid? uploadID, int? chunkNum, byte[] data)
```

Note how the method prototype has a byte array?